# SQLite query only returning first record

Tags: database, sqlite

I have created a members SQLite table that, when queried, only returns the first row. The table has 11 fields, most are TEXT and 9 and 10 are DATE. Here is a snapshot of the data:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NYqC.png

The following view query, along with many simpler variations of it, only returns the first record:

```
CREATE VIEW test_monthly_filter AS
    SELECT first_name,
           last_name,
           email,
           join_date,
           type_code,
           status,
           nac_num,
           nac_bill,
           change_date,
           comments
      FROM member
     WHERE status = 'A' OR 
           change_date = '10/15/18';
```

Any ideas on what is causing this? Thanks!

Comment: Of what type exactly is the `status` column? My guess is that it might be treated as fixed char column by the front-end and that it might contain white spaces to fill up till max length. How are you retrieving the records in the front-end (if avail)?.

Comment: status column is of type TEXT. I am using SQLite studio 3.1.1. Hope that helps Olivier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have data quality issues, if status = 'A' only returns one row, that means only one row satisfies the criteria of status = 'A'.

You can try something like:

```
WHERE status LIKE '%A%'
```

If that returns the rows you are interested in that means you probably have leading or trailing spaces.